# How to get exec to run on IIS 6.0

Tags: php, windows, iis, imagemagick, exec

I installed the software imagemagick on my server *"Windows Server 2008"*.

In cmd it works fine, all commands work.

But when I try to do it in PHP:

```
$command = "convert fdfdf.jpeg dfdf2.jpeg";
exec($command, $output);
```

It does not work. I get a blank page and nothing happens,

I have given all the permissions I need to the following:

```
cmd.exe
whomi.exe
c:\ImageMagick. execute & read to iis_iusrs and everyone.
```

*Safe Mode are off*.

What else can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$command = "convert fdfdf.jpeg dfdf2.jpeg 2>&1";
exec($command, $output);
var_dump($output);
```